# How to connect local SQL Server database from Docker compose

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, api, docker-compose

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project in VS2022, using a SQL Server database on my local laptop, everything was fine. After that I have added dockerfile and dockercompose then after when I run the project, I could see api from swagger but none of the end points are working since it gives error as

> System.Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.

I could understand that, from docker its not able to connect to my SQL Server database installed on my laptop, am I right?

Could you please guide me to how to resolve this error since, I'm new to Docker.

Comment: Are you using an Named Instance of SQL Server, or `LocalDB`, or the Express edition?

Comment: im using named instace its LAPTOP-CRJKTD15\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: also i have seen that SQL Server Browser is running under services.msc but, still api is giving erro from docker compose

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the host that you're using to connect to your database to `host.docker.internal` as that's how the host machine should be referenced from inside of a Docker container. You can read more about that in the Docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).

Comment: I have changed the Data Source=host.docker.internal:1433 OR Data Source=host.docker.internal OR Data Source=gateway.docker.internal but, none helped